# Preventing Drag & Drop when drop position is occupied

Tags: reactiveui

I'm started experimenting with ReactiveUI, and I'm stuck on how to implement a simple drag and drop. I'm dragging rectangles around an itemscontrol, that has a grid for a panel. I've got the basic drag and drop working, but I want to prevent
dropping if the grid cell is occupied, and change the mouse cursor while the mouse is being dragged over an occupied cell. I have a dictionary of , and I use the messagebus to retrieve the contents, either null or MyObject, then send another message back with the result.

```
 MessageBus.Current.Listen<Point>().Subscribe(gp =>
        {
            MessageBus.Current.SendMessage(SegmentMap.ContainsKey(gp) ? SegmentMap[gp] : null);
        });
```

Now that I have the result I can't figure out how to use it to modify my drag and drop Observable method chain, ie instead of

```
 mouseMove.TakeUntil(mouseLeftUp)
```

something like

```
 mouseMove.TakeUntil(mouseLeftUp && IsCellClear == true)
```

I'm using WPF, and MVVM. Here's my main observable:

```
    var dropGridPosition = mouseLeftDown.SelectMany(start => mouseMove.TakeUntil(mouseLeftUp),
                        (start, end) => new DropGridPosition(new Point {X = end.X - start.X, 
                                                                        Y = end.Y -start.Y}, start))
                                                                     .Where(p => !p.DropOffset.Equals(_offsetZero))
                                                                     .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

Comment: Is this WPF, UWP, or something else? And can you share a bigger portion of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure you can't use Bind instead of MessageBus (or pass around a Observable if need be). MessageBus is usually a bad abstraction in most cases inside RxUI (ReactiveUI).

With your TakeUntil you'd probably likely want to combine both your MouseUp event and a WhenAnyValue() to your AllCell property.

something like this:

```
var isCellNotClear = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CellValue).Select(x => x != null);
// CombineLatest will take the multiple observables, 
// and with a lambda convert them into Observable with the result from the lambda.
var isCellNotClearOrLeftButtonUp = isCellNotClear.CombineLatest(mouseLeftButtonUp,
   (isCell, isMouseUp) => isCell || isMouseUp);
mouseMove.TakeUntil(isCellNotClearOrLeftButtonUp);
```

Comment: You may need to add Skip(1) to isCellNotClear observable (this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CellValue).Select(x => x != null).Skip(1)). This is because WhenAnyValue() will send default(T) when it is initialized and you don't want to trigger until a real change happens and the value is changed.